# Python LXML fails to find XML element

Tags: python, xml, lxml, saml

I'm attempting to find an XML element called "md:EntityDescriptor" using the following Python code:

```
def parse(filepath):
    xmlfile = str(filepath)
    doc1 = ET.parse(xmlfile)
    root = doc1.getroot()
    test = root.find('md:EntityDescriptor', namespaces)
    print(test)
```

This is the beginning of my XML document, which is a SAML assertion. I've omitted the rest for readability and security, but the element I'm searching for is literally at the very beginning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor ...
```

I have a namespace defining "md" and several others:

```
namespaces = {'md': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata'}
```

yet the output of `print(test)` is `None`.

Running `ET.dump(root)` outputs the full contents of the file, so I know it isn't a problem with the input I'm passing. Running `print(root.nsmap)` returns:

```
{'md': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata'}
```

Comment: If md:EntityDescriptor is the root element, trying to find a child md:EntityDescriptor element with `find` isn’t going to work. You’ve already selected that element as `root`.

Comment: @DanielHaley sure enough, that was the issue. However, the problem is that I need to run this same operation on multiple files, and md:EntityDescriptor is not always the root element. Is there a way to find an element regardless of whether or not it's the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `md:EntityDescriptor` is the root element, trying to find a child `md:EntityDescriptor` element with find isn’t going to work. You've already selected that element as root.

> However, the problem is that I need to run this same operation on multiple files, and md:EntityDescriptor is not always the root element. Is there a way to find an element regardless of whether or not it's the root?

Since you're using lxml, try using [xpath()](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#xpath) and the `descendant-or-self::` axis instead of find:

```py
test = root.xpath('descendant-or-self::md:EntityDescriptor', namespaces=namespaces)
```

Note that `xpath()` returns a list.